# Unexplained right-side margin when page not full screen - Nuxt/Tailwinds

Tags: html, css, vue.js, tailwind-css

I am trying to make just a simple CV page, using Nuxt, Vue3 and TailwindCSS. When my browser is full-screen, everything looks fine, and it all fits in well. However, if I got anything outside of full-screen, there is a margin for no explicable reason on the right-side of the page in my main body part of the application. (Please overlook the horrible design, it's still in progress)

As displayed below, there is a margin on the right side of the element, but shouldn't be and its not showing in the computed layout even. I have no custom CSS added, so I am only using the default Tailwind-supplied classes, as far as I can tell, there should be no right-side margin. [image: image of problem]

This is the parent element, which as you can see has no padding or margins that would affect the child.
[image]

Here is my `default.vue`, where the "content" elements are inserted (in the `<slot />` tag)

```html
<template>
    <div class="container flex p-4 flex-col h-screen overflow-hidden bg-slate-200">
        <div class="pb-2 bg-gradient-to-r from-red-500 via-green-500 to-purple-500">
            <header class="bg-slate-200 pb-2">
                <nav>
                    <ul class="flex justify-end gap-5">
                        <NuxtLink to="skills" class="rounded-lg border-black border-solid border-2
                                p-3">
                            <li>Key Skills & Interests
                            </li>
                        </NuxtLink>
                        <NuxtLink to="education" class="rounded-lg border-black border-solid
                                border-2 p-3">
                            <li>Education</li>
                        </NuxtLink>
                        <NuxtLink to="experience" class="rounded-lg border-black border-solid
                                border-2 p-3">
                            <li>Experience</li>
                        </NuxtLink>
                        <NuxtLink to="about" class="rounded-lg border-black border-solid
                                border-2 p-3">
                            <li>A Little Bit About Me</li>
                        </NuxtLink>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </header>
        </div>

        <slot />
    </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Container class in tailwind doesn't apply any horizontal padding or self-center automatically. Adding mx-auto class (which sets margin-left and margin-right to auto) to the first div will solve the problem.

Comment: Stackover flow is a not a place to solve problem but to educate them. Its better to add explanation